.NET MAUI Background Processing on iOS
I am making a pedometer/activity tracker where I am trying to both count steps and also read accelorometer data consistently when the application enters the background. I am using the BGProcessingTaskRequest from the BackgroundTasks library. However, when the phone screen is locked, the app will no longer process data (I am sending a small MQTT message each time when debugging).
I am developing on a Windows machine onto a physical iPhone 12. I have enabled everything background related in info.plist, including background, fetch etc.
All code is from the App Delegate in app-name/project/Platforms/iOS
/AppDelegate.cs
I am registering like this.
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FinshedLaunching called ...");

        BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Register("com.domain.com.backgroundprocessing", null, (task) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registered about to call backgroundprocessing");
            PerformBackgroundprocessing((success) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Backgroundprocessing !!!");

                task.SetTaskCompleted(success);
            });
        });

I am scheduling like this:
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
        base.DidEnterBackground(application);

        Console.WriteLine("Entered background");

        nint taskId = 0;

        // Begin a background task to extend execution time
        taskId = application.BeginBackgroundTask(() =>
        {
            // Handle expiration of background task
            application.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
        });

        var appTaskProcessingRequest = new BGProcessingTaskRequest("dk.au.besafe.backgroundprocessing")
        {
            EarliestBeginDate = NSDate.Now
        };


        BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Submit(appTaskProcessingRequest, out NSError error2);

        if (error2 != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error submitting backgroundprocessing request: {error2.LocalizedDescription}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Background processing task request submitted successfully. Should run within 10-20 minutes");
        }

        // End the background task
        application.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
    }

I am processing like this:
/// <param name="completionHandler"></param>
    private async void PerformBackgroundProcessing(Action<bool> completionHandler)
    {
        // Perform background processing here
        // This method will be called when the system determines it's appropriate to perform background processing
        Console.WriteLine("PerformBackgroundprocessing called");
        //await ConnectAsync();

        // Once the background processing is complete, call the completion handler with the appropriate result
        // Pass true if processing was successful, otherwise pass false
        completionHandler(true);
    }


You may refer to iOS Backgrounding with Tasks. Tasks are under a strict time limit, and typically get about 600 seconds (10 minutes) of processing time after an application has moved to the background on iOS 6, and less than 10 minutes on iOS 7+.
